# Integer incrementation crashes application

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a file line-by-line, and storing that line of data in a object called 'command' (which holds information on what instructions a robot object can understand)

Here is the read function (C++):

```
int robot::readfile(const char fname[]) {
    FILE *rf;
    rf = fopen(fname, "r");

    if (rf != NULL) {
        int idx = 0;
        char record[161];

        while ((this->cmd_count < this->cmd_size)
               && (fgets(record, 160, rf) != NULL)) {
            command tmp_cmd(record);
            this->cmds[idx++] = tmp_cmd;
        }
    } else {
        perror(fname);
    }

    fclose(rf);
    return 1;
}
```

So basically, in the code above, when I try incrementing the variable "idx" by 1 (using the syntax: idx++), it basically just crashes the application.

Any ideas why?

EDIT:
As reqested by a commenter:

```
void robot::cmd_malloc(int size) {
    // most likely will cause problems if size is below 1.
    if (size < 1) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        this->cmds = new command[size];
        this->cmd_size = size;
        this->cmd_count = 0;
    } catch (std::bad_alloc) {
        // bad allocation exception.
        this->cmds = NULL;
        cout << "bad_alloc:" << (sizeof(command) * size) << " in 'robot::cmd_malloc'." << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what's causing the crash, and not the fact that you're indexing into a table `cmds` that you haven't properly initialized?  Can we see the code where you initialize `cmds`?

Comment: You're never incrementing `this->cmd_count`?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I even tried taking the increment out of the array. And sure - updating question now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not incrementing `cmd_count` in the loop, which means at some point `idx` becomes greater than `cmd_size` which causes program to crash.

The C++ style of writing the code is to use:

- `std::vector<command>` instead of `new command[size]`. If you use `std::vector`, then you dont have to do memory management yourself, plus you don't have to maintain two other variables `cmd_size` and `cmd_count` as vector itself gives those information through `size()` and `capacity()` member function, respectively.
- `std::ifstream` instead of `FILE*`. And while reading input in the loop, you should just use `std::string` instead of `char[161]`, though I'm *not* sure about this part, as I don't know exactly what data you're attempting to read from the stream.

Comment: Thanks - it seems to have fixed the problem.

Also about your suggestions on coding style - thanks for the tips, but sadly my professor only allowed us to use what we've been taught  throughout the last two semesters.